# Impala Connection error

Tags: hive, impala

I am trying to run the below impala command in my cloudera cluster

```
impala-shell  -i connect 10.223.121.11:21000 -d prod_db -f /home/cloudera/views/a.hql
```

but I get error as

```
 Error, could not parse arguments "10.223.121.11:21000"
```

Could some one help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flag `-i` should be defined as: `-i hostname or --impalad=hostname` (without `connect`)

command `connect` should be used within `impala-shell` [Connecting to impalad through impala-shell](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/cdh/5-1-x/Impala/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_connecting.html)

> The default port of 21000 is assumed unless you provide another value.

So this should works:

```
impala-shell --impalad=10.223.121.11 -d prod_db -f /home/cloudera/views/a.hql
```

Answer (score 0):

In own scenario, I was connected with the `impala-shell` but suddenly I got `[Not connected] >` . Trying to reconnect failed & I didn't want to restart my machine (which is another option).
And Trying this:

`[Not connected] > CONNECT myhostname`
did not help either

I realized that my IP did change. 
By just adjusting my IP from dynamic to static fixed it.